# Requesting the ability to work from home

Tags: professionalism

A bit of background info...

I moved to a new town along with my partner around 8 months ago to start work at a software house. The job has been great so far, but I think moving was a mistake as the area does not suit us well. I would like to ask my boss about the possibility of remote working so that I can return home, seeing as other employees of the company are allowed to do so. These employees commute to the office once or twice a week.

Also, my partner requires a driving license for her current job, which has recently been revoked. This limits her range of opportunities in the area, so it could be hard to find employment without a license.

What would be the best way to approach my supervisor to ask if this is a possibility? I am not looking for a short term solution. I would like the ability to work from home for say, 3 days per week and then commute to the office for 2 days.

Comment: I think I am after a more long term solution to my problem

Comment: Explain your Situation. (to your Boss) 9/10 they will value you enough to come up with Solutions even if they might be temporary. But this does really Sound more like a travel Problem for your Partner/spouse. I am not ignoreing the fact that you are not likeing the new area so far, but more you being covered with Problems and are not enjoying what it has to offer which might fade over time.

Comment: "Does not suit us well" often just takes more time to settle in.  However,  you can certainly ask, and you do so simply by asking. Don't be surprised if they tell you that they want longer experience with you before they are comfortable with you working unsupervised; that too often requires more time.  You may just have to carry your partner until the revocation elapses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good question to ask is why, if others are allowed to work from home, are you not?

Is it that you're still very new to the company? Is it that your position requires a lot more on-site interaction with certain employees? Are those other employees who work from home fellow developers, or staff with a wildly different function within the company?

Your partner has definitely hit a snag, however also remember that you were hired under a certain understanding. By all means talk to your boss, just remember that asking for special treatment doesn't make a good impression, and it may, or may not work out.