# How to handle unfair workplace policies in Ireland?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, parental-leave, ireland

I am pregnant and struggling with insomnia and my commute doesn't help the situation. I asked my manager if I could work at home and he said no. Naturally, I am not impressed with the situation. I'm a software developer so there's no reason for me not to work at home.

I recently discovered that another male coworker has been working at home pretty much whenever he feels like it. He's taking a part time course that's not related to the company.

I'm really not happy about this.

Also, there was another woman who went on maternity leave who got a lunch before she went on leave. I recently found out that they are not going to plan a lunch for me.

My boss has also said things in relation to me going on mat leave such as: 'this is a really tricky situation for us' , he had doubts about me coming back, and complained that I only have him 3 months notice when the company policy says 4 weeks is needed for mat leave.

I am not sure what to think about the situation or how to address the issues.

Comment: This sounds very much like your previous question https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/114489/3176

Comment: I've been working there for over a year. Ireland. He said he'd find it hard to talk so because of this I've had to suffer.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you do not have a legal right to work from home, and just because someone else was allowed to do so doesn't mean you can force them to let you. High performers might get special treatment even in a situation like this. Did you get good reviews?

Comment: I'm guessing this is not Germany because something like this would definitely not fly over here.

Comment: Why not ask your manager why your co-worker is able to work from home and you cannot?

Comment: *"I'm really not happy about this [male coworker working at home due to college course]"* - This is the wrong strategy, if you are thinking about pursuing it. Don't claim you should be able to work from home because someone else works from home. Instead make the case on you own merits, like medical needs due to the pregnancy.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to speak with HR regarding making reasonable adjustments to working conditions etc and the issue about giving notice as you’ve given more than the policy requests.

In terms of the lunch etc, there’s not much that can be done. Although it seems that it’s unfair, it’s probably not in the company policy so not much can be done.

Comment: There is no HR at this company.

Comment: There is always someone who fills the *role* of HR even if that isn't their title.

Comment: @PhilipKendall if the company is small enough, her boss may be that person.

Comment: I was reading up on this a few days ago @alroc. Depending on the country it may be worth getting advice from a union.

Comment: @user1261710 In your OP, you said a new company policy enacts a 4 weeks notice. Who writes the policy? That is the HR point of contact.